# How is the Meta participation calculated?

Tags: support, meta

Recently, while randomly browsing Meta Ask Ubuntu, I found the [Participation](https://meta.askubuntu.com/users?tab=participation) tab in the [Users](https://meta.askubuntu.com/users) section. To me, it is showing me on the top of the tab:

[image]

But I haven't posted any meta posts recently, so, I believe it shows the current user on the top of the page.

Am I correct? Does it show the current user on top? How is participation calculated on Meta?

Comment: Even if the algorithm behind this metric is semi-secret, I think this metric should be quantified/scored (assigned a number) so that it can be presented on moderation election candidacy cards.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's a tooltip on the "Participation" button at the top, which you can see if you hover over it:

> Users most active on this site in the last 60 days (combined number of posts, votes, comments and edits).

[This post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149097/377214) elaborates more on it:

> Take the sum of those four values and sort the users based on those sums. The only minor details that are not in the tooltip are things like "don't count deleted stuff", and the fact that "votes" includes answer acceptance and that "edits" excludes edits to your own posts.

As site metas don't have reputation, the designers needed a different way to order users who participate on them, so this is what they came up with.

Incidentally, this sort order is also available on main sites despite there not being a link to it; it can be accessed by going to `/users?tab=participation`.